# Rich Text Area fields do not display correctly in Visualforce email template

Tags: apex

I have an email template that I built as a visualforce template. In my template. I am using rich TextArea field where user can write text in any formate(i.e. It can have bullet points or paragraphs). But when templates fetch the value from VF component, it converts the whole field value in single paragraph.
For Example : if below is my field value

```text
Testing XYZ:

• Testing 1
• Testing 2
• Testing 3

Another paragraph with few lines:

• Line 1
• Line 2
```

It converts the whole field value like below, which does not looks good while reading :

```text
Testing XYZ:• Testing 1• Testing 2• Testingt 3Another paragraph with few lines:• Line 1• Line 2
```

Is there any way to keep the format of the field to as it is?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! In order to format text very specifically/explicitly on any of the Stack Exchange sites, you should surround that text with three backticks (```) above and below the text, which will format it as a code block. That is OK to use even if it is not code, but that is best way to format text in an exact manner. I edited your question and formatted it in the way that I *thought* you were intending for it to look. If that is not correct, please edit your question and change my edits to make it look correct.

Answer (score 0):

In visualforce Email Template, Just add `<pre>` tag around the textarea field.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Your Order has been booked" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity" >
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<div style="width: 100%">   
    Hi,
    <b>Description:</b> <pre>{!RelatedTo.Descriptions__c}</pre>
    <br />
    Thanks!<br />
    {!recipient.Name}
    
</div>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```